# How do I wait for the value of a firebase realtime database reading?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am stuck trying to do the following: when a button is clicked I need to check a value from my realtime database (I have to wait for the response), if the value exists I have to do some stuff (publish new data), but if the value doesn't exist then do nothing.

The code that I have so far:

```
  let ref3 = firebase.database().ref("dispositivos")

  ref3.once('value').then(function (snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasChild("value")) {
        console.log("exists");
          ref.update({ //Link mac to user
            [p]: cant,
            [cant]: mac
          }).then(function(){
            console.log("Link done!");
            });
        }
    }
    else {
       // if the child doesn't exist, do other code
    }
  });
```

I tried to use `then` as I read in some posts and `await` but they don't seem to work. Sometimes the code works, but sometimes not (this occurs both when "value" exists and when it does not).

Comment: Hey, first of all the example you shared doesn't work because of an extra `}` before the `else`. Besides that, are you getting any errors? Have you tried adding a catch block after every `then`? Please provide more information.

Comment: Hey, I apologize, just before uploading the question I had tried something that a colleague had told me and I forgot to delete that '}'. Answering your question, no  I dont get any errors, sometimes it works and sometimes we could say it omits the reading part,  since if I put console logs after and before they work.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "omits the reading part"...  does it skip the entire `if else` block? Anyway the only thing i can think of right now is trying to catch errors with `.catch` after the `then`. or you can try success and failure callbacks as mentioned in the [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#once)